# android how to detect the cancel button click on Connect to Googledrive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

When a user try to connect to GoogleDrive for downloading , the authentication form is displayed, w user google account... working fine when the user click OK , but how can I capture the Cancel button click to send an intent to another activity ...?
the only check is "onItemClick"...

```
            // Connect to Google Drive, access to all files
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
        startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

        OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener()  {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                downloadItemFromList(position);
                finish();
            }
        };
```

I tried to catch the cancel exception, but it's not accepted

```
        try {
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

and I am not sure which cancel operation it's catching ...

Answer (score 0):

I should handle the respons ein the  onActivityResult {}
damned !  too late ... stop working for today